# Find particular string from URL in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have some URLs like:

```
staging.myurl.com
dev.myurl.com
qa.myurl.com
```

I get these urls from json, json can have these URLs or any other url as well, But I want to find URLs which matches myurl.com, whatever will be the postfix or prefix of this URL, that does not matter. How can I do it using regex?

Comment: you mean this `\S*myurl\.com\S*` ?

Answer (score -1):

You could use the `indexOf` method:

```
url.indexOf('myurl.com')
```

if the result is greater than -1, then  `myurl.com` is contained in the `url`.

Please try the following demo

```js
var array = ['staging.myurl.com', 
             'dev.myurl.com', 
             'qa.myurl.com', 
             'r1.random.com',
             'fake.domain.com'];

// The last two items in the array will not be shwon in the alert.

var desiredUrls = [];

for(var i=0; i<array.length; i++)
   if(array[i].indexOf('myurl.com')>-1)
     desiredUrls.push(array[i]);

alert(desiredUrls);
```